# How to handle Objects with arrays to access specific data?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, foreach

I'm new to working with objects in PHP. I have a JSON object with print_r output that looks like this (please see below). I've edited it to shorten it, but this is the structure of it:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [STATION_2CHAR] => ST
    [STATIONNAME] => Summit
    [ITEMS] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ITEM] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ITEM_INDEX] => 0
                            [SCHED_DEP_DATE] => 07:55:00 08/02/2013
                            [DESTINATION] => Dover
                            [TRACK] => 1
                            [LINE] => M&E
                            [TRAIN_ID] => 6607
                            [STATUS] => All Aboard
                            [SEC_LATE] => 322
                            [BACKCOLOR] => green
                            [FORECOLOR] => white
                            [SHADOWCOLOR] => black
                            [GPSLATITUDE] => 
                            [GPSLONGITUDE] => 
                            [GPSTIME] => 8/2/2013 7:59:37 AM
                            [TRAIN_LINE] => Morris & Essex Line
                            [STATION_POSITION] => 1
                            [LINEABBREVIATION] => M&E
                            [INLINEMSG] => 
                            [STOPS] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [STOP] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [NAME] => Chatham
                                                    [TIME] => 8/2/2013 8:05:31 AM
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [NAME] => Madison
                                                    [TIME] => 8/2/2013 8:08:43 AM
                                                )

                                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [NAME] => Convent Station
                                                    [TIME] => 8/2/2013 8:12:56 AM
                                                )

                        ... etc
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ITEM_INDEX] => 1
                            [SCHED_DEP_DATE] => 08:07:00 08/02/2013
                            [DESTINATION] => Hoboken
                            [TRACK] => 2
                            [LINE] => M&E
                            [TRAIN_ID] => 414
                            [STATUS] => in 8 Min
                            [SEC_LATE] => 81
                            [BACKCOLOR] => lightgreen
                            [FORECOLOR] => black
                            [SHADOWCOLOR] => lightgreen
                            [GPSLATITUDE] => 40.6951
                            [GPSLONGITUDE] => -74.4034
                            [GPSTIME] => 8/2/2013 7:59:59 AM
                            [TRAIN_LINE] => Gladstone Branch
                            [STATION_POSITION] => 1
                            [LINEABBREVIATION] => M&E
                            [INLINEMSG] => 
                            [STOPS] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [STOP] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [NAME] => Maplewood
                                                    [TIME] => 8/2/2013 8:14:53 AM
                                                )

                                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [NAME] => South Orange
... etc
```

This is the type of PHP coding method I have been using to access this data. I'm wondering if there is a better way, because it becomes kind of complex with having to "foreach" loop through it to get at what I need. I had the impression with Objects in PHP I would be able to access the data more directly.

Here is some PHP code I wrote. It's a function and while it has worked from my unit testing of it so far, I have the feeling there is a better way to do this to be more elegant in the programming. This function has two nested foreach loops and three "if" statements. That just seems like a lot to me to find the connection times for a trip.

```
// $trip is the Object from the above data sample.
function get_connection($trip,$final_desired_dest,$connection_time) {

foreach ($trip as $st_key=>$st_ny_trip) {

$xfer_depart_time = $st_ny_trip->SCHED_DEP_DATE;


if ($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP instanceof stdClass)
{
    $st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP = array($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP);
}

foreach ($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP as $key=>$value) {

    if ($value->NAME == $final_desired_dest ) {
        $connect_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $connection_time);
        $xfer_depart_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $xfer_depart_time);
        $final_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $value->TIME);

        if ($xfer_depart_raw > $connect_raw) {
            $xfer = $xfer_depart_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
            $final = $final_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
            return array ($xfer,$final);
        } // if (second)
    } // if (first)
}
} // foreach (first)
    return array ("","");
} // function end
```

I'm looking for a better method to improve on this. I might be greatly overlooking how to make full use of the Objects and OO programming here, so I look forward to being enlighten. Thanks!

Comment: first just convert the hole thing to array, **print_r(json_decode($json_data, true));** . thanks

Comment: Please provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Improve in what regard? You have an array nested in your object, such you have to work with that portion of your object as an array. You might consider using `array_filter()` or similar to find you item in the nested array rather than iterating over it.

Comment: Blithely converting everything to arrays is unhelpful. It makes it easier on coding because you don't have to remember what is an object and what isn't, but it removes the opportunity to encapsulate code and use objects intelligently. Both JSON and XML usually convert to the types of arrays above,  and it's therefore more painful to convert them to actual objects. But it's worth it to convert things properly to take full advantage of the language and of work you have already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A start to using objects and arrays is to use objects for **somethings** and arrays for **lists** (0,1, many, lots) **of somethings**. An oversimplification, but it gets things started. Objects are particularly useful when they can answer a question about themselves (does this train stop in X?) as you code it once and use it often.

Since you have your objects in JSON and were showing a `print_r`, I assume that you are able to translate the raw data to whatever format you want. The format you show has some extra fields that are necessary for the data interchange, but maybe superfluous when using it in programming. I would recommend removing unhelpful fields/levels (the *STOP* in *STOPS*, e.g.) and converting lists to arrays, other items to objects.

I brute-forced the data into the structure I'd use below. It allows code like this:

```php
    $oScheduleDeparture = generate_scheduled_departure_1();
    $oStation = generate_station();

    print_r($oScheduleDeparture->getConnection('Madison', '3/4/2013 3:14:00 AM'));
    print_r($oStation->goesToDestination('Hoboken'));
    print_r($oStation->getConnections('Madison', '3/4/2013 3:14:00 AM'));
```

You should be able to write a parser to convert your raw data into something similar. Hope it helps!

---

```php
    class Station {

            public function goesToDestination($destination) {
                $aReturn = array();
                foreach ($this->ITEMS as $oScheduledDeparture) {
                    if ($oScheduledDeparture->goesToStation($destination)) {
                        $aReturn[] = $oScheduledDeparture;
                    }
                }
                return $aReturn;
            }

            public function getConnections($destination, $connection_time) {
                $aReturn = array();
                foreach ($this->ITEMS as $oScheduledDeparture) {
                    if ($oScheduledDeparture->goesToStation($destination)) {
                        $aReturn[] = array(
                            'SCHED_DEP_DATE'    => $oScheduledDeparture->SCHED_DEP_DATE,
                            'DESTINATION'       => $oScheduledDeparture->DESTINATION,
                            'CONNECTION'        => $oScheduledDeparture->getConnection($destination, $connection_time),
                        );
                    }
                }
                return $aReturn;
            }

        }

        function generate_station() {

            $aStation = array(
                STATION_2CHAR   => 'ST',
                STATIONNAME     => 'Summit',
            );

            $oStation = new Station();
            foreach ($aItem as $key=>$value) {
                $oStation->$key = $value;
            }

            $oStation->ITEMS = array(
                generate_scheduled_departure_0(),
                generate_scheduled_departure_1(),
            );
            return $oStation;
        }

        class ScheduledDeparture {

            public function getScheduledDepartureTime() {
                return $this->SCHED_DEP_DATE;
            }

            public function goesToStation($destination) {
                if ($this->DESTINATION == $destination) {
                    return true;
                }

                // check stops
                foreach ($this->STOPS as $STOP) {
                    if ($STOP->NAME == $destination) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            public function getConnection($destination, $connection_time) {
                $connect_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $connection_time);
                $xfer_depart_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $this->getScheduledDepartureTime());

                foreach ($this->STOPS as $STOP) {
                    if ($STOP->NAME == $destination) {
                        $final_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $STOP->TIME);

                        if ($xfer_depart_raw > $connect_raw) {
                            $xfer = $xfer_depart_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
                            $final = $final_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
                            return array ($xfer,$final);
                        } 
                    }
                 }
                 // no connection available
                 return false;
            }
        }

        function generate_scheduled_departure_0() {
            $aItem = array(
                'ITEM_INDEX'        => '0',
                'SCHED_DEP_DATE'    => '07:55:00 08/02/2013',
                'DESTINATION'       => 'Dover',
                'TRACK'             => '1',
                'LINE'              => 'M&E',
                'TRAIN_ID'          => '6607',
                'STATUS'            => 'All Aboard',
                'SEC_LATE'          => '322',
                'BACKCOLOR'         => 'green',
                'FORECOLOR'         => 'white',
                'SHADOWCOLOR'       => 'black',
                'GPSLATITUDE'       => '',
                'GPSLONGITUDE'      => '',
                'GPSTIME'           => '8/2/2013 7:59:37 AM',
                'TRAIN_LINE'        => 'Morris & Essex Line',
                'STATION_POSITION'  => '1',
                'LINEABBREVIATION'  => 'M&E',
                'INLINEMSG'         => '',
            );

            $oScheduleDeparture = new ScheduledDeparture();
            foreach ($aItem as $key=>$value) {
                $oScheduleDeparture->$key = $value;
            }

            $oScheduleDeparture->STOPS = generate_scheduled_departure_0_stops();
            return $oScheduleDeparture;
        }

        function generate_scheduled_departure_0_stops() {

            $aStops = array();

            // 
            $aStop = array(
                'NAME' => 'Chatham',
                'TIME' => '8/2/2013 8:05:31 AM',
            );
            $aStops[] = (object)$aStop;

            $aStop = array(
                'NAME' => 'Madison',
                'TIME' => '8/2/2013 8:08:43 AM',
            );
            $aStops[] = (object)$aStop;

            $aStop = array(
                'NAME' => 'Convent Station',
                'TIME' => '8/2/2013 8:12:56 AM',
            );
            $aStops[] = (object)$aStop;

            return $aStops;
        }

        // item 1
        function generate_scheduled_departure_1() {
            $aItem = array(
                'ITEM_INDEX'        => '1',
                'SCHED_DEP_DATE'    => '08:07:00 08/02/2013',
                'DESTINATION'       => 'Hoboken',
                'TRACK'             => '2',
                'LINE'              => 'M&E',
                'TRAIN_ID'          => '414',
                'STATUS'            => 'in 8 Min',
                'SEC_LATE'          => '81',
                'BACKCOLOR'         => 'lightgreen',
                'FORECOLOR'         => 'black',
                'SHADOWCOLOR'       => 'lightgreen',
                'GPSLATITUDE'       => '40.6951',
                'GPSLONGITUDE'      => '-74.4034',
                'GPSTIME'           => '8/2/2013 7:59:59 AM',
                'TRAIN_LINE'        => 'Gladstone Branch',
                'STATION_POSITION'  => '1',
                'LINEABBREVIATION'  => 'M&E',
                'INLINEMSG'         => '',
            );

            $oScheduleDeparture = new ScheduledDeparture();
            foreach ($aItem as $key=>$value) {
                $oScheduleDeparture->$key = $value;
            }

            $oScheduleDeparture->STOPS = generate_scheduled_departure_1_stops();
            return $oScheduleDeparture;
        }

        function generate_scheduled_departure_1_stops() {

            $aStops = array();

            $aStop = array(
                'NAME' => 'Maplewood',
                'TIME' => '8/2/2013 8:14:53 AM',
            );
            $aStops[] = (object)$aStop;

            $aStop = array(
                'NAME' => 'South Orange',
                'TIME' => '8/2/2013 8:08:43 AM',
            );
            $aStops[] = (object)$aStop;

            $aStop = array(
                'NAME' => 'Convent Station',
                'TIME' => '8/2/2013 8:14:25 AM',
            );
            $aStops[] = (object)$aStop;

            return $aStops;
        }
```

Comment: Excellent! I like your comments also about the data development to get rid of unhelpful items for the task. And leading to it's usage such as, "print_r($oScheduleDeparture->getConnection..." was extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks good, except that you don't need to update `$connect_raw` and `$xfer_depart_raw` each inner-iteration, as the source value doesn't change. Also, you can make the `$xfer_depart_raw > $connect_raw` decision earlier as both values don't change in the inner-loop:

```
// $trip is the Object from the above data sample.
function get_connection($trip,$final_desired_dest,$connection_time) {
    $connect_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $connection_time);
    foreach ($trip as $st_key=>$st_ny_trip) {
        $xfer_depart_time = $st_ny_trip->SCHED_DEP_DATE;
        $xfer_depart_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $xfer_depart_time);

        if ($xfer_depart_raw <= $connect_raw)
            continue;

        if ($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP instanceof stdClass)
            $st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP = array($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP);

        foreach ($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP as $key=>$value) {
            if ($value->NAME == $final_desired_dest) {
                $final_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $value->TIME);
                $xfer = $xfer_depart_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
                $final = $final_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
                return array($xfer, $final);
            }
        }
    } // foreach (first)
    return array ("","");
} // function end
```

An other way is to use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with a closure:

```
// $trip is the Object from the above data sample.
function get_connection($trip,$final_desired_dest, $connection_time) {
    $result = array("", "");
    try {
        array_walk($trip, function(&$st_ny_trip, $st_key) use (&$result) {
            $xfer_depart_time = $st_ny_trip->SCHED_DEP_DATE;
            $xfer_depart_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s m/d/Y", $xfer_depart_time);
            if ($xfer_depart_raw > $connect_raw) {
                array_walk(array($st_ny_trip->STOPS->STOP), function(&$value, $key) use (&$result) {
                    if ($value->NAME == $final_desired_dest) {
                        $final_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y g:i:s a", $value->TIME);
                        $xfer = $xfer_depart_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
                        $final = $final_raw->format("m/d/Y g:i:s a");
                        $result = array($xfer, $final);
                        throw new Exception(); // get out
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }
    return $result;
} // function end
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with two data types at same time is hell, and you sad you have json data. so pass true when you decode json. that way every thing will be converted to array.

> When you pass TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
print_r(json_decode($json_data, true));
```

if you don't have json data, then simply first encode to json then decode it. Because there is no other way to convert all Std classes to arrays in array (or in stdClass).

```
print_r(json_decode(json_encode($data), true));
```

it's more easy to work with one data-type than two.
hope that will help.